# How to handle multiple conditions of instance variable assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have the following in my controller that will assign a different collection of results depending on what params are received with an Ajax call. It is messy and i would like to just call a function with all the logic in rather than all this in my index controller

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:literacy_param].present?
      @skills = Skill.search(params)
    elsif params[:numeracy_param].present?
      @skills = Skill.numeracy_default_params
    elsif params[:numeracy_number_skills].present?
      @skills = Skill.numeracy_number_skills
    elsif params[:numeracy_measuring_skills].present?
      @skills = Skill.numeracy_measuring_skills
    elsif params[:numeracy_data_skills].present?
      @skills = Skill.numeracy_data_skills
    else
      @skills = Skill.default_params
    end
  end
end
```

Im just a bit unsure on how to set out my function so that it can read the params that are being sent,

I have come up with this so far

```
private
 def skills(params)
   if params[:literacy_param].present?
     @skills = Skill.search(params)
   elsif params[:numeracy_param].present?
     @skills = Skill.numeracy_default_params
   elsif params[:numeracy_number_skills].present?
    @skills = Skill.numeracy_number_skills
   elsif params[:numeracy_measuring_skills].present?
    @skills = Skill.numeracy_measuring_skills
   elsif params[:numeracy_data_skills].present?
    @skills = Skill.numeracy_data_skills
   else
    @skills = Skill.default_params
   end    
 end
```

Then in my index action i would do

```
@skills = skills(params)
```

would this be an efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: just info. you can also do `@skills = if condition ... end` instead of repeating `@skills` all over. being DRY ;)

Comment: @Nithin Hehehe. Good DRY. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    skills = ['literacy_param', 'numeracy_param', 'numeracy_number_skills', 'numeracy_measuring_skills', 'numeracy_data_skills']
    common_in_params = (skills & params).first
    @skills = common_in_params.present? ? (common_in_params.eql?('literacy_param') ? Skill.search(params) : Skill.send(common_in_params)) : Skill.default_params                
  end
end
```

You can define `skills` array in an initializer for resusability

Comment: There is a small difference to the original implementation - if `literacy_params` is an empty string it will use the default. I would go with `common_in_params  = skills.find {|skill| params[skill].present?}` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be this:

```
def skills(params)
  set_of_skills = params.slice(
    :numeracy_param,
    :numeracy_number_skills,
    :numeracy_measuring_skills,
    :numeracy_data_skills,
  ).first

  @skills = if params[:literacy_param]
    Skill.search(params)
  elsif set_of_skills
    Skill.public_send(set_of_skills)
  else
    Skill.default_params
  end
end
```

I would also advise to have this extracted into a `lib/` folder, and unit-tested. So that in your controller you could perform the following:

```
def index
  @skills = SkillSearch.new(params).search
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of doing this right now:

1. Wrap the params in a unique key. As in `params = { :keyword => :literacy_param }`, and then use this unique key to identify the right operation.

In you *skill.rb*:

```
def self.filter(params)
  if params[:keyword] == :literacy_param
    search(params)
  elsif available_filters.include?(params[:keyword])
    public_send(params[:keyword])
  else
    default_params
  end
end

private

  def self.available_filters
    %i{numeracy_default_params numeracy_number_skills numeracy_measuring_skills numeracy_data_skills}
  end
```

considering that instead of `:numeracy_param`, you send `:numeracy_default_params` in `:keyword` key. Otherwise you'll have to make another `elsif` inside `filter` method.

then in your `index` method:

```
def index
  @skilles = Skill.filter(params)
end
```

2. You create a separate filter class, which is an expandable solution, just in case when you need to go for complex search queries and filtering.

Let's call it `SkillSeacrher`, inside you *app/models/skill_searcher.rb*:

```
class SkillSearcher
  attr_reader :keyword

  def initialize(keyword)
    @keyword = keyword
  end

  def filter
    if keyword == :literacy_param
      Skill.search(params)
    elsif available_filters.include?(keyword)
      Skill.public_send(keyword)
    else
      Skill.default_params
    end
  end

  private

    def self.available_filters
      %i{numeracy_default_params numeracy_number_skills numeracy_measuring_skills numeracy_data_skills}
    end
end
```

then in `index` method:

```
def index
  @skills = SkillSearcher.new(params[:keyword]).filter
end
```

However, you can do one more change to `filter` method(depends on your taste):

```
def filter
  if keyword == :literacy_param
    Skill.search(params)
  else
    Skill.public_send(available_filters.include?(keyword) ? keyword : :default_params)
  end
end
```

And, if you have all these methods accepting `params` as arguments then it'd be much more sleek:

```
def filter
  Skill.public_send(available_filters.include?(keyword) ? keyword : :default_params, params)
end
```